# Limit of a subsequence of non decreasing functions valued on a compact set.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f^n(•)$ be a sequence of non decreasing cadlag functions valued in some set let's say [0,C].

Im reading an article which says it is kinda obvious it admits a subsequence which converges to a certain uniformly lipschitz continuous function $f(•)$. Maybe i lack the background but it is not obvious at all for me. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Heh, the word "obvious" serves no legitimate purpose in mathematical writing.

Comment: Not every nondecreasing cadlag function is Lipschitz, so even if $f_n = f $ for all $n $, this is not true.

Comment: What is a cadlag function?

Comment: Actually it is bounded by another sequence which has a lipschtiz limit so i guess it is ok thanks !

Comment: Cadlag os continu à gauche limité à droite. Right continuous, left limit

Comment: @RiezFrechetKolmogorov "**c**ontinue **à** **d**roite, **l**imite **à** **g**auche". Gauche = left, droite = right